# Touch/ swipe events including when swiping on an iframe and make it slideable

Tags: jquery, iframe, slider, touch, slide

I am using touchslider.com which is a jquery plugon to allow mouse and touch swiping on areas of a page to have a nice one page basic app where 4 pages can be swiped between

the problem i am having is that on one slide is an iFrame. this area of the screen therefore become un-swipeable. can anyone suggest anything?

I guess the question is more around adding swiping affect to the iframe.

Thanks

dan

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to slide (perhaps up/down) inside the iframe as well? If not, you could have a transparent div overlaying the iframe which would prevent the touch event from getting lost in the frame.

Comment: Yes but wouldn't that make the content in the iframe unclickable ie links etc?

Comment: Yep it would, thats the tradeoff for the easy way out I guess.